# How to have many markers in a fusion tables layer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

In my efforts with FTL I've learned that :

**A.** You can only have 5 markerOptions styles in a layer.

**B.** If you have 1 layer styled with markerOptions, you can't style any additional layers.

I'd like to use Fusion Table Layers for my map project but this is making my life really difficult, as I'd like to have more than five markers.

Are there any workarounds?

How is [this](http://newspapermap.com/) made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style limitations you mention only apply to Fusion Table layers created via the GMap API. The workaround is to use the Fusion Table User Interface.

E.g. One of the tables used by the Newspaper map you linked above is http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=552892

Click Visualize Map and then, if it's your own table, choose Configure styles. There are several ways to set as many markers as you like (so long as they are the official FT marker names).  Based on values from other columns, based on a column containing the marker name, etc.
These styles will show up in your GMap application.

Comment: @wije Just realized this is related to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9939109/1211981) But I'm sure there's a solution combining both the FT UI and the GMap API but it's not clear what your goal is

Comment: Well, my goal is to set the letter icons A-J, on the 10 markers closest to the coords of a geolocation request in the browser. After your answer in my prev question I tried to do it with several layers, but no such luck. Not really sure how to use the UI for this purpose.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done.  Since the geolocation is random, i.e. varies for each query and you want 10 styles it won't work. You can only have 5.  BUT ... The map display itself answers the question of which are closest. Is it really necessary to label them A thru J?

Answer (score 0):

This help article gives the nitty gritty on styling maps in the Fusion Tables web app. 
http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185991

This can provide a base style for any of the 5 layers. The dynamic styles you describe using in the Fusion Tables Layer can then be used to override the base style in one layer, if you like.